# The pipe endpoint could not be found on your local machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, endpoint

I installed 3rd party web application and changed the port to 212 via Bindings in IIS.

Below is my Bindings screenshot.

[image: Site Bindings]
However, when I tried to run a feature in the application, it gives error:

> The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost//' could not be found on your
>   local machine.

It seems the `net.pipe` can't find my web application in **localhost** while my web application is in **localhost:212**.

Can someone please advise whether the fault is in the code of application or I miss a configuration in IIS?